# Percentage of New Accounts and Repeat

Tags: ssis, ssms

Good Afternoon,

I am new to sql, but working on a project where they want a random sample of 59 accounts where 67% are new and the other 33% are repeat.

Would anyone know of a way to accomplish this? I know i can use Select Top (67) Percent with Ties * from table where reason is new.

Is there a way to accomplish both in 1 query?

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you want is two fold.

1. Random Sample: Use your top logic and order by a new column called NEWID(). This will create a random GUID.
2. One query:

   ```
   ;with cte_New as
   (select top 67 percent
      [FieldList]
    ,guid = newid()
   from AuditDetail
   where AcctType = 'new'
   order by guid)

   , cte_old as
   (
   select top 33 percent
    [FieldList]
    ,guid = newid()
   from AuditDetail
   where AcctType = 'old'
   order by guid
   )

   select * from cte_New
   union all
   select * from cte_Old
   ```

Comment: thanks for the advice, that worked perfectly for getting what i needed. I do have a follow up question what if the users is now requesting instead of identifying a certain percentage, they want to calculate the entire file first and find the percentage for new vs repeat. How would i set that file up?

Answer (score 0):

Follow up is easier.

```
Select acctype, count(*), count(*)/tot
From table
Cross apply (select count(*) from table) ca(tot)
```